# R: how to interpret the output of factor analysis by "fa {psych}"

Tags: r, factor-analysis

Parts of both outputs of the functions "*factanal*" (base) and "*fa*" (psych package) are shown below.

Interpreting the output of *factanal*: It says that the (theoretical) factor-model differs significantly from the empirical data.

I am not able (even after consulting the documentation of the *psych* package) to determine, which output of *fa* is analogous to the above output of *factanal*.

**Question:** Which chi-square from *fa* tells how well the factor-model fits the data?

### factanal (base)

```
Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.
The chi square statistic is 18.66 on 4 degrees of freedom.
The p-value is 0.000917
```

### fa (psych)

```
Mean item complexity =  1.2
Test of the hypothesis that 2 factors are sufficient.

The degrees of freedom for the null model are  15  and the objective function was  2.47 with Chi Square of  945.53
The degrees of freedom for the model are 4  and the objective function was  0.05 

The root mean square of the residuals (RMSR) is  0.03 
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.05 

The harmonic number of observations is  382 with the empirical chi square  7.57  with prob <  0.11 
The total number of observations was  387  with Likelihood Chi Square =  19.71  with prob <  0.00057 

Tucker Lewis Index of factoring reliability =  0.936
RMSEA index =  0.102  and the 90 % confidence intervals are  0.059 0.147
BIC =  -4.12
Fit based upon off diagonal values = 1
Measures of factor score adequacy             
                                                   MR1  MR2
Correlation of (regression) scores with factors   0.93 0.91
Multiple R square of scores with factors          0.86 0.82
Minimum correlation of possible factor scores     0.71 0.65
```